# Find the multiplicative order of $10$ modulo $2003$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Find the multiplicative order of $10$ modulo $2003$, i.e the least positive integer $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod {2003}$.

I haven't learned about this yet, does this mean I have to find $k = \text{ord}_{2003}10$?
Any hints to solve this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use Fermat's Little Theorem, or Lagrange's theorem. Note that $2002 = 2\times 7 \times 11 \times 13$.

Comment: The order must divide $\varphi(2003)=2002$ (Result is $1001$)

Comment: Do you mean that I have to use $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$, so that will be: $10^{2002k} \equiv 1 \pmod {2003}$? Am I right about this?

Comment: $10^{2003-1}\equiv 1 mod(2003)$  so $(10^{2002})^{\frac 12}\equiv 1 mod (2003)$ so $10^{1001}\equiv 1 mod (2003)$. So the least power is $1001$

Comment: My mistake, it supposed to be $10^{2002} \equiv 1 \pmod{2003}$, but how did you come up with $(10^{2002})^{\frac{1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{2003}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Remember to include your work on the problem, otherwise it looks like you are asking others to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Find the multiplicative order of $10$ modulo $2003$, i.e the least positive integer $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod {2003}$.
>
> ...does this mean I have to find $k = \text{ord}_{2003}10$?

Yes, that's the definition of $\text{ord}_n$.

First to note/check is that $2003$ is prime. This means under Fermat's little theorem that $10^{2002}\equiv 1 \bmod 2003$, and thus we know that $k$ divides $2002 = 2\cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13$, giving $16$ options, $k \in \{1,2,7,11,13,14,22,26,77,91,143,154,182,286,1001,2002\}$,  two of which are obviously wrong ($1$ and $2$).

Calculating, we get $10^7 \equiv 1024 \bmod 2003$ which is interesting since $1024 =2^{10}$ is a square, so - since we were looking at an odd power of $10$ - there must be some value $r$ such that $r^2\equiv 10 \bmod 2003$ (we don't need to find it), meaning $r^{2002} \equiv 10^{1001}\equiv 1 \bmod 2003$, so $k\mid 1001$ and all the even possibilities for $k$ are eliminated.

So I leave you to calculate which of $\{11,13,77,91,143,1001\}$ is the answer sought.

Comment: note that if $10^{143}\not\equiv1$, then $10^{11}\not\equiv1$ and $10^{13}\not\equiv1$

Comment: yeah, working down through the powers is a good option. I wasn't going to do all the work.

Comment: Wow, this is a very detailed answer. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question is that what if the modulo is not prime? If it's not prime then I can't use Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: It's more complicated, but Euler's totient ($\phi$) takes the place of $p{-}1$ to some extent. You can also view it as simultaneously solving the problem for all of the prime powers of the modulus, which leads you most of the way to the Carmichael function ($\lambda$).

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: I like the observation about $10^7$. You can also use the law of quadratic reciprocity (and its extension handle $2$) to see that neither $2$ nor $5$ is a quadratic residue. Hence $10=2\cdot5$ is.